# Accessing Abstract Class Methods C#,ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding, abstract-class, abstract

I have the following classes in my program and now I want to access the method M2() present in the class Y. I tried to access it by creating the object of class Z and then casting it with variable of class X and calling x.M2(10,5) but instead of class Y it is still invoking the method M2() present in the class X. Thanks.

```
public partial class Abstract_Class : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Z z = new Z();
        int r1 = z.M2(10, 20); //gives output -20
        X x = z;
        int r2 = x.M2(10,5); //gives output 10 while I want it to print 15
    }
}
public class W
{
    public virtual int M2(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }
}
public abstract class X : W
{
    public abstract void M1();
    public override int M2(int x, int y)
    {
        return 2*(x-y);
    }
}
public abstract class Y : X
{
    public sealed override int M2(int x, int y)
    {
        return 3 * (x - y);
    }
}
public class Z : X
{
    public override void M1()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks for the comment.I tried this but its throwing InvalidCastException, saying "Unable to cast object of type 'Z' to type 'Y'."

Comment: Well `Z` isn't a `Y`. `Z` is an `X` but not a `Y`. I also don't see where you're trying to cast it to a `Y`. Also, I don't see a `static` `M3` method defined on `Z` but you're calling it on the third line of your `Page_Load` method. Is the code posted here the _actual_ code you're running?

Comment: I see your updated code, but `Y` still isn't part of this equation anywhere. Did you mean to have your `Z` inherit from `Y`? That is have `public class Z : Y`? EDIT: Even so, you aren't hiding or changing methods really. Simply assigning your `z` to an `X` won't change much; it will still perform the virtual override resolution and call the highest level `override` on `M2`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Sorry for that static method M3(), actually I had removed it from class X but forgot to remove in the main class, I have edited it. So is it possible to access the method present in the class Y, with this piece of code?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks for the reply.Yes actually this is the code which I have got and I had been asked to invoke the method M2() of class Y, I tried everything but no luck.

Comment: You would need to create an instance of `Y`. Since it's `abstract`, you would have to create some subclass of it. Say `public class SubY : Y { }`. Then in your code write something like `var suby = new SubY(); suby.M2(10, 5);`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks. I'll do this accordingly. +1 for the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create an instance of `Y`. Since it's `abstract`, you would have to create some subclass of it.

```
public class SubY : Y
{

}
```

Then in your code write something like:

```
var suby = new SubY();
int r2 = suby.M2(10, 5); //15
```